# Payment is working but does not create transaction on order

Tags: magento2, orders, payment, transaction

Payment is working fine, order status is changed but Transactions is empty.
How can i get Transactions data on order?

Comment: Which payment method are using?

Comment: i use woldpay extension

Comment: https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-magento2  this module?

Comment: yes it is what i use